# How to import a CSV into two different SQL tables that reference each other with Python

Tags: python, postgresql, csv

**Objective**

I am working on CS50 Web's Project 1, Books (https://docs.cs50.net/ocw/web/projects/1/project1.html). It requires that I import a csv into a database of one or two tables. The CSV looks like:

```
isbn, title, author, year
0131320931, The Hobbit, J.R.R. Tolkien, 1937
```

I chose to make two tables: books and authors. They look like:

```
CREATE TABLE books (book_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, isbn VARCHAR(13), title VARCHAR(26021), author references authors(author_id),  year INT);
CREATE TABLE authors (author_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(255));
```

My goal is to use a Python script with SQLAlchemy to import the CSV into both of those tables.

**Issue**

My issue is importing the CSV in such a way that the foreign id in books references authors. My current code is as such:

```
def main():
    f = open("books.csv")
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for isbn, title, author, year in reader:
        db.execute("INSERT INTO authors (name) VALUES(:author)",
                   {"author": author})
        db.execute("INSERT INTO books (isbn, title, year) VALUES(:isbn, :title, :year)", {
                   "isbn": isbn,
                   "title": title
                   "year": year})
    db.commit()
```

The result is:

```
 book_id |    isbn    |         title         | author | year 
---------+------------+-----------------------+--------+------
       1 | 0380795272 | Krondor: The Betrayal |   *    | 1998
       2 | 1416949658 | The Dark Is Rising    |        | 1973
*Should be "1", the foreign key for Raymond E. Feist.
```

```
 author_id |       name       
-----------+------------------
         1 | Raymond E. Feist
         2 | Susan Cooper
```

I can't quite seem to wrap my head around a way to import them simultaneously that generates the foreign key in author. I thought of creating a temporary table and using SELECT WHERE queries, but that seemed like a cop out. I also tried a nested function in the second INSERT into books using authors, but that didn't seem to work.

I am using PostgreSQL.

Any help is appreciated, as well as feedback on how I've posed the question!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

I was able to figure it out. I used PostgreSQL's `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING` clause after making the `authors.name` column unique. One caveat, which in this data structure I think is unavoidable, are authors with the same name. I also am not sure how I would include books that are written by multiple authors.

#### Code

```
def main():
    f = open("books.csv")
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    reader.__next__
    for isbn, title, author, year in reader:
        db.execute("INSERT INTO authors (name) VALUES(:author) ON CONFLICT (name) DO NOTHING",
                   {"author": author})
        db.execute("INSERT INTO books (isbn, title, author, year) VALUES(:isbn, :title, (SELECT author_id FROM authors WHERE name = :author), :year)", {
                   "isbn": isbn,
                   "author": author,
                   "title": title,
                   "year": year})
    db.commit()
```

#### Output

```
 author_id |       name       
-----------+------------------
        38 | Raymond E. Feist
```

```
 book_id |    isbn    |         title         | author | year 
---------+------------+-----------------------+--------+------
      38 | 0380795272 | Krondor: The Betrayal |     38 | 1998
```

*Note: It's incidental that they share the same ID because they were the first records inputted.*